# Can I mix new and old batteries in a parallel circuit?

Tags: batteries

I mean non rechargeable alkaline batteries like energizer's, some full, some half empty. I know I cannot do that in series, I forgot why, but what about parallel?

I found answers for rechargeable batteries only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fresh batteries will attempt to 'charge' the older batteries, since there will be a voltage difference.

Depending on the type of battery, and the differences in voltage, the results may be anything from "It works just fine" to bulging and/or leaking and/or overheating batteries.  The latter because these are not rechargeable.

With rechargeable batteries, the batteries with the higher voltages will charge the lower voltage batteries until they equalize.

Comment: Do we assume fresh batteries in parallel will lose voltage in sync and not produce these problems?

Comment: Yes, in sync enough anyway.

Comment: match if voltage is almost same for best performance. But ESR rises with age so less is less so less effect when weak when dead it is like C drops to <5% and ESR is 20x bigger so it acts like a lousy ecap of 1mF with higher ESR in kiloohm range when dead, Voc/Isc=ESR

Comment: @Exocytosis It can only happen once, when you connect them the first time. When they're in parallel the voltages stay in sync automatically.